# InDesign reports a missing font when exporting, but this font is not being used anywhere

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, export

When i export this particular document to PDF i get the first message below. I already know Myriad is not being used and when i click `Find font` you can see Myriad is not listed. But i do get the error, and strangely, if i export again immediately after, with no other changes, the error doesn`t show up the second time.

Presumably some object still has a Myriad character trailing somewhere, but how can i clean this up? (using ID CS6)

[image: missing font]

[image: find font]

Comment: Check out the addition edits I made to [this question you edited](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/79656/revisions). It's best to fix all the problems with a question if you're going to take the time to edit it :) Let me know when you read this so I can delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the 'Basic Paragraph' style, which is unused in my document, was set to use the Myriad font. This is why the export reported this missing Myriad although i knew it wasn't used anywhere. Updated my 'Basic Paragraph' style to use Verlag Book instead, which was already used heavily in the document, and all is good now.